# Comparing strings is "1"<"seven"

Tags: java, compare

If i were to compare the String "1" to the string "7" which one would be bigger. Also if I compare the string "1" to the string "Test" which one would be bigger?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: `<`, `>`, `>=`, and `<=` only apply to primitive types.

Comment: @Jeffrey:  `String.compareTo()` and `String.compareToIgnoreCase()` returns an int (which is primitive).  So technically you're right...

Comment: Haha! Interesting question. The < operator hasn't been overloaded for `String`s, so this wouldn't work in Java at all.

Comment: I did, and it didn't work. I know there is the compareTo() method but I am also confused on how that works. I am a true newbie sorry:(

Comment: You could have asked this question in more general terms, for exsample "How to compare strings in java?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparison of Strings in Java is done character by character.  Each character has a specific ranking to it based on where it appears in the Unicode character table (for this case, we can use [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii_code#ASCII_printable_characters), since it's English).

"1" would be considered less than "7", as well as "T".

To invoke (place this inside of `main()`:

```
System.out.println("1".compareTo("7"));
System.out.println("1".compareTo("Test"));
System.out.println("1".compareToIgnoreCase("7"));
System.out.println("1".compareToIgnoreCase("Test"));
```

You'll get negative valued results - these are the distances in terms of ASCII point from the character you're comparing to.  `compareToIgnoreCase()` compares the values within the lowercase ASCII range, so this is why the value of the last `compareToIgnoreCase()` is so low.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was curious about.